# Catchable fatal error: Object of class Forma could not be converted to string in on line 35

Tags: php, class

I am new to php currenlty learnig, I am trying to learn objects, and i have problem with this code. It says that problem is with my postavi_html function.
I would realyl apreciate any advice, thank you in advance

```
class Forma
{
    private $method;
    private $action;
    private $pun_html;

    function __construct ($metoda,$akcija)
    {
        $this->method = $metoda;
        $this->action=$akcija;
    }

    function gen_inputs($n)
    {
        $s="";
        for($i=0;$i<$n;$i++)
        {
            $s .="<input type='textfield' name='text$i' placeholder='text$i'/><br>";
        }
        $s .="<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Posalji'/><br>";
        return $s;
    }
    function gen_links ($href,$text,$color)
    {
        $s="<a style='color:$color;' href='$href'>$text</a>";
        return $s;
    }
    function postavi_html($broj_inputa,$href_linka,$text_linka,$boja_linka)
    {
        $this->pun_html = "<form method='$this->method' action ='$this->action'>$this-> gen_inputs($broj_inputa) . $this->gen_links($href_linka,$text_linka,$boja_linka)</form>";

    }
}

$forma= new Forma ("GET","nesto.php");
echo $forma-> postavi_html (4,"GOOGLE","www.google.com","#564898");
```

Comment: It's not the cause of your error, but what exactly are you expecting to be `echo`ed? Your `postavi_html` function doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to include complex fields in a string you can do the following:

```
$string = "normal and now {$a->getSomething()}"
```

to better see what is happening add the following function to your class:

```
function __toString() { return 'myObject'; }
```

php is trying to convert $this to a string. This is how the function should look like:

```
function postavi_html($broj_inputa,$href_linka,$text_linka,$boja_linka)
{
    $this->pun_html = "<form method='{$this->method}' action ='{$this->action}'>{$this->gen_inputs($broj_inputa)} . {$this->gen_links($href_linka,$text_linka,$boja_linka)}</form>";
}
```

Comment: wow, that was realy fast, thank you guys, i preciate it very much :D

Answer (score 0):

It seems the problem is with using $this->method, $this->action in the postavi_html function. Try the below code

```
function postavi_html($broj_inputa,$href_linka,$text_linka,$boja_linka)
{
    $this->pun_html = "<form method='".$this->method."' action ='".$this->action."'>".$this->gen_inputs($broj_inputa) . $this->gen_links($href_linka,$text_linka,$boja_linka)."</form>";
   // If you want to return the form.
   return $this->pun_html;
}
```

Note the change
'$this->method' to '".$this->method."'

Output:

```
<form method="GET" action="nesto.php">
    // inputs
</form>
```

Comment: it works , actualy both of your advices were very useful, thank you guys you saved  from coupple of hours staring at the monitor :D